# How do I extract an ID, select the correct view model from a list and pass this inside a partial?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm fairly new to MVC.

I have the following scenario: I have a list of quotes on a QuoteDetails page. I click on a quote and it takes me through an ItemDetails page where I can view a list of associated items.

An item belongs to a quote and a quote can have many items. These items are listed on a sidebar on ItemDetails page.

```
@model QuotePageViewModel

 <div class="list-group">
    @{bool firstItem = true;}
    @foreach (var quote in Model.LiveQuotes)
    {
        if (firstItem.Equals(true))
        {
            firstItem = false;
            <a href="#" id="@quote.Item.ItemID" class="list-group-item active">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>@quote.Item.Title<span class="badge">ItemID: @quote.Item.ItemID</span>
            </a>
        }
        else
        {
            <a href="#" id="@quote.Item.ItemID" class="list-group-item">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>@quote.Item.Title<span class="badge">ItemID: @quote.Item.ItemID</span>
            </a>
        }
    }
</div>

<div class="col-sm-9">
    @Html.Partial(MVC.Item.Views.ViewNames._TabbedItemDetailsPanel, ViewData)
</div>
```

This lists all my items as expected.

When I select an item, I want to grab the correct ItemViewModel in my partial. What would be the best way to do this?

I have a few ideas but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish them. For example, one is:

The class that is active, grab the Item ID use linq to filter LiveQuotes and select the QuotesOverviewViewModel pass this into the partial.

Or would an ajax call be better suited for this?

I have a QuotePageViewModel that looks like this:

```
public class QuotePageViewModel : PageViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<QuotesOverviewViewModel> LiveQuotes { get; set; }
}

public class QuotesOverviewViewModel : DataViewModel
{
    public QuoteViewModel Quote { get; set; }
    public CustomerViewModel Customer { get; set; }
    public QuoteStatusViewModel QuoteStatus { get; set; }
    public OriginatorViewModel Originator { get; set; }
    public ItemViewModel Item { get; set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel : DataViewModel
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public int? QuoteID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }
    public Money Price { get; set; }
    public QuoteViewModel Quote { get; set;}
}
```

Hope that's clear. Please ask if you don't understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was looking at it the wrong way around.

The following worked out for me.

I extended the QuotePageViewModel

```
public class QuotePageViewModel : PageViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<QuotesOverviewViewModel> LiveQuotes { get; set; }
    public PaginatedViewModel<QuotesOverviewViewModel> ArchivedQuotes { get; set; }
    public ItemViewModel SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

I set the value in my ViewModelService. On page load I added this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Item.ActionNames.ItemDetail, MVC.Item.Name, new { itemId = @quote.Item.ItemID })" id="@quote.Item.ItemID" class="list-group-item active">
```

Updated the partial:
    @Html.Partial(MVC.Item.Views.ViewNames._TabbedItemDetailsPanel, Model.SelectedItem)

Hope this helps someone.